# Instantiate a module from variable contents

Tags: perl, module

I feel like this might be a silly question or possibly even one of those unexpectedly inflammatory ones; still I am curious.

I have a configuration file I read in, and then based on the contents create objects of different types. A good model would be a library catalog. Lets say I have packages (classes) Books::Historical, Books::SciFi, Books::Romance, etc. And the config has hashes like

```
%book = (
  type => 'SciFi',
  name => 'Journey to the Center of the Earth',
  ...
);
```

As I read the conf file I want to create objects of these types. I know I could do something like:

```
my $book_obj;
if ($book{'type'} eq 'SciFi') {
  $book_obj = Books::SciFi->new();
  #do stuff with $book_obj
} elsif ($book{'type'} eq 'Romance') { ...
```

but I was wondering if there is some way to do something more like

```
my $book_obj = Books::$book{'type'}->new();
```

so that I don't need to setup a huge if tree?

PS. yes, I will probably contain this functionality inside the Books package, that is to say  not exposed, but I will need to deal with this eventually any way I do it.

Comment: You should look at http://www.iinteractive.com/kiokudb/ - KiokuDB: Persistent Object Graphs for Perl.

Comment: If the project gets that big I will think about some real persistence. For now these are just some flat-file JSON for config. I wanted something "human-readable" but still structured. Actually since Perl isn't compiled I really could just use a Perl file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just construct the classname by putting it in a scalar, then instantiate:

```
my $classname = 'Books::' . $book{type};
my $book_obj = $classname->new;
```

Remember that the LHS of the `->` operator can be pretty much anything that evaluates to an object or classname.

So you could also do something like this:

```
my $book_obj = ${ \"Books::$book{type}" }->new;
```

but that's pretty ugly.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have a feeling you a right, but I am having trouble making my (more complicated, real) code work. Had to change the @ISAs to our from my, but still complaining.

Comment: `@ISA` needs to be a package (`our`) variable, but you probably shouldn't be changing it directly; `use base 'Foo'` is the right way to declare inheritance relationships, or even better, `use parent` if you have it available.

Comment: Thanks for that, got it working. I do have parent, is that better?

Comment: @Joel, `base` has some cruft that can't be removed for backwards-compatibility reasons.  `parent` is a fork of `base` with that cruft removed.

Comment: PS, I wish the `perldoc perlop` on "->" was as clear as you put it!